# How to convert elements from JSON to String in Cypress

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I try to loop throough a json file where i need an order_id and a postalcode to check the status in the track and trace portal. But when i use this code is get this error:

```
cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined
```

```
{
    before(() =>
    {
        cy.fixture('Planning_Client_Loop').as('ttdata')
        cy.viewport(1620, 1080)
    })
    it('Loop through track trace data', function()
    {
        const trackTraceData = this.ttdata
        cy.get(trackTraceData).each((ttObject) =>
        {
            cy.visit(Cypress.env('TRACKTRACE_BASEURL'));
            cy.get('#tracking-code').type(ttObject.order_id)
            cy.get('#order-postcode').type(ttObject.postal_code)
            cy.get('#submit-button').click()
            cy.get('#status-message').should('contain', 'Delivery is planned')
        })
    })
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
   "Track Trace Data": [
      {
         "order_id": 4425566,
         "postal_code": 20300
      },
      {
         "order_id": 4424891,
         "postal_code": 20301
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: JSON is a string?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i used the code above and I get this error: ```cy.type() can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefinedLearn more```

Comment: But how can you convert JSON to a string? JSON is already a string.

Comment: json.Stringify is a possibility https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

[`cy.get()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Syntax) gets you an elements (or more) in the DOM. I don't see anything in your example JSON file that suggest it would make sense to pass it into cy.get().

You're perhaps looking for `forEach()`:

```js
cy.visit(Cypress.env('TRACKTRACE_BASEURL'));

this.ttdata['Track Trace Data'].forEach(data => {
    cy.get('#tracking-code').type(data.order_id)
    cy.get('#order-postcode').type(data.postal_code)
    cy.get('#submit-button').click()
    cy.get('#status-message').should('contain', 'Delivery is planned')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to provide the array `cy.get(trackTraceData["Track Trace Data"]).each...` name ('Track Trace Data') to get the exact array from your json file from which you need to get value. I only changed that line of code and now it should work!

```
before(() =>
{
  cy.fixture('Planning_Client_Loop').as('ttdata')
  cy.viewport(1620, 1080)
})
it('Loop through track trace data', function()
{
  const trackTraceData = this.ttdata
  cy.get(trackTraceData["Track Trace Data"]).each((ttObject) =>
  {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('TRACKTRACE_BASEURL'));
    cy.get('#tracking-code').type(ttObject.order_id)
    cy.get('#order-postcode').type(ttObject.postal_code)
    cy.get('#submit-button').click()
    cy.get('#status-message').should('contain', 'Delivery is planned')
  })
})
```

Comment: I used a forEach() and that does the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have done the following: i also added a loop to go through different screensizes as well because we use different ID's for finding certain fields and buttons. So now i had to use the beforeEach(). And i have to select the correct Array before i use the forEach().

```
beforeEach(() =>
{
    cy.fixture('Planning_Client_Loop').as('ttdata')
    cy.fixture('viewport').as('viewportdata')
})
it('Loop through track trace data with Mobile screensize', function()
{
    this.viewportdata['screenSizeMobile'].forEach(viewPortSize => {
        cy.viewport(viewPortSize.screen)
    this.ttdata['Track Trace Data'].forEach(ttObject => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('TRACKTRACEPORTAL_BASEURL'));
        cy.get('#tracking-code').type(ttObject.order_id)
        cy.get('#postcode').type(ttObject.postal_code)
        cy.get('#submit-button').click()
        cy.get('#mobile-status-message').should('contain', 'Delivery is planned')
        })
    })
})
it('Loop through track trace data with Desktop screensize', function()
{
    this.viewportdata['screenSizeDesktop'].forEach(viewPortSize => {
        cy.viewport(viewPortSize.screen)
        this.ttdata['Track Trace Data'].forEach(ttObject => {
            cy.visit(Cypress.env('TRACKTRACEPORTAL_BASEURL'));
            cy.get('#tracking-code').type(ttObject.order_id)
            cy.get('#order-postcode').type(ttObject.postal_code)
            cy.get('#submit-button').click()
            cy.get('#desktop-status-message').should('contain', 'Delivery ois planned')
        })
    })
})
```